I'm implementing SecurityFilterChain and setting it up so that only admins have access. When I log in with the admin,doesn't allow me access
I'm implementing SecurityFilterChain and setting it up so that only admins have access to that endpoint. When I log in with the admin account, it doesn't allow me access.
My code
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EndToEndSecurityDemo{
    private final EndToEndUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/"),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login"),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/error"),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/registration/**")
                        )
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/**")
                        )
                        .hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((login)-> login
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .usernameParameter("email")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout)-> logout
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                )
                .csrf(withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}

@Data
public class EndToEndUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean isEnabled;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public EndToEndUserDetails(User user) {
        this.userName = user.getEmail();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.isEnabled = user.isEnabled();
        this.authorities =
                Arrays.stream(user.getRoles().toString().split(","))
                        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EndToEndUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .map(EndToEndUserDetails::new)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }
}


At registration, I set the user as a 'user'.
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService implements IUserService{
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final VerificationTokenService verificationTokenService;

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User registerUser(RegistrationRequest registration) {
        var user = new User(registration.getFirstName(), registration.getLastName(),
                registration.getEmail(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(registration.getPassword()),
                Arrays.asList(new Role("USER")));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
    @Override
    public Optional<User> findByEmail(String email) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found")));
    }
    @Override
    public Optional<User> findById(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void updateUser(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        userRepository.update(firstName, lastName, email, id);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        Optional<User> theUser = userRepository.findById(id);
        theUser.ifPresent(user -> verificationTokenService.deleteUserToken(user.getId()));
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}


In the database, I have the tables 'user', 'role', and 'user_role'. I changed the name of the role to 'ADMIN' and restarted the application, but it's still the same.

You should pass the role with the prefix ROLE_ to new SimpleGrantedAuthority(). Example: ROLE_ADMIN
Unfortunately, you did not provide an example of the Role class, so I cannot see how you have implemented it. Please check that the prefix is present.

like this this.authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
.map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
